# how to get data from helper function in a desire format?

Tags: php, laravel

i made a  file helper.php and then made a class in it there is a function in it which return all the categories. what i want to do is to get the categories and the show in to the dropdown menu. but i dont know how to do it.

```
<?php
    namespace App\helpers;
    use App\category;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    class Helper
    {
        public static function shout(string $string)
        {
            return strtoupper($string);
        }
        public static function categories()
        {
            $obj = category::all();
            return $obj;
        }
    }

?>
```

This is the helper class.

```
{!!Helper::categories()!!}
```

This is how i call the function in the template.

```
[
 {"id":1,"name":"samsung","created_at":"2020-09-18T11:08:47.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-09-18T11:08:47.000000Z"}, 
 {"id":2,"name":"nokia","created_at":"2020-09-18T11:08:51.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-09-18T11:08:51.000000Z"}, 
 {"id":3,"name":"iphone","created_at":"2020-09-18T11:08:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-09-18T11:08:55.000000Z"}
]
```

It returns data like this. but I want the only the name of the category and want to show in the dropdown menu. Please tell me how to do this

Comment: You're returning and outputting every `category` model from your database. You're getting exactly what you defined... You can do `@foreach(Helper::categories() as $category) {{ $category->name }} @endforeach`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing JSON to the user, try using Blade to make the responses into a dropdown. Something like this:

```php
<select name = "name">
@foreach(Helper::categories() as $element)
    <option value = "{{ $element->name }}>" {{ $element->name }} </option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Which would make something like this:

```html
<select name = "name">
    <option value = "samsung"> samsung </option>
    <option value = "nokia"> nokia</option>
    <option value = "iphone"> iphone </option>
</select>
```